# grunt-bower-task and Polymer

Tags: gruntjs, polymer, bower

I cannot seem to find an easy way to copy *all* the files from **Polymer** to using **grunt-bower-task**.

```
grunt.initConfig({
    bower: {
        install: {
            options: {
                targetDir: 'wwwroot/lib',
                layout: 'byComponent',
                install: true,
                copy: true,
                verbose: true,
                cleanTargetDir: false,
                bowerOptions: {}
            }
        }
    }
```

I understand that only the `main` files defined inside each element's **bower.json** file get copied over. I am also aware that I could put a `exportsOverride` section in my own **bower.json** to include more files like this -

```
  "exportsOverride": {
    "*": {
      "": "*.*",
      "demo": "demo/*.*",
      "test": "test/*.*"
    }
  }
```

But this doesn't cover all cases as some elements have more sub-folders than just *demo* and *test*. Do I have to manually look them all up and add their paths to the `exportsOverride`, or there's an easy way that I've overlooked?

Comment: https://github.com/davidmaxwaterman/yeoman-chromeapp/blob/master/Gruntfile.js   and @256 for a sample "copy" tag that may help you with bower.

Comment: also note changes to property names among bower/polymer/grunt   "copy"

Comment: In addition, not all the elements have set the 'main' property set at its bower. I opened an issued related to that https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-elements/issues/31

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hate to provide a sample of a fail....

FWIW recently , i had very similar issue ... worked it and failed

what i did is abandon the attempt to flatten everything out in the "dist" tag for a first polymer project.  Rather i just ran minify/ugly on one or two elements leaving the HTTP2 type file structure ( deep and many many, dirs/files. )

```
// the process belo NG . Manual edit needed on "polymer-min.html" go end and chg the js file name   
    copy: {
      main: {
        files: [
          // includes files within path
          {expand: true, src: ['*html'], dest: 'dest/', filter: 'isFile'},
          // includes files within path and its sub-directories
          {expand: true, src: ['js/**', 'images/**' ,'css/**' ,'elements/**' ,'bower_components/**'], dest: 'dest/'},
        { src: ['tmp/csp/build-csp.html'], dest: 'dest/bower_components/cast-button-polymer/cast-button-polymer-min.html', 
            filter: 'isFile',
            options: {
              process: function (content, srcpath) {
                return content.replace(/build-csp.js/g,"cast-button-polymer-min.js");
              },
            },
            },
        { src: ['tmp/csp/build-csp-min.js'], dest: 'dest/bower_components/cast-button-polymer/cast-button-polymer-min.js', filter: 'isFile'},         
        ],
      },
},
```

Comment: Thanks! I eventually went with my own way but the link you provided really helped.